# How to exclude rows from a SQL query with an "IF"-like condition

Tags: sql-server-2008, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have a feeling that this answer is staring at me right in the face...I just can't see it.  I've also ran into this problem many times, but I can't seem to wrap my head around a solid answer for it.  I need to exclude some rows from my SQL query with just a simple condition.  Here is my code:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#NextEvent') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #NextEvent
CREATE TABLE #NextEvent(

  CaseDisplayNumber VARCHAR(20)
, ScheduledDay DATETIME
, EventTypeID INT
, EventType VARCHAR(50)
, EventResult VARCHAR(50)
, MatterTypeID INT
, RowNum INT

)
INSERT INTO #NextEvent
SELECT CC.CaseDisplayNumber
    ,SD.ScheduledDay 
    ,SE.EventTypeID EventTypeID
    ,ETC.EventType EventType
    ,ERC.EventResult 
    ,MTC.MatterTypeID 
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CC.CaseDisplayNumber ORDER BY SD.ScheduledDay DESC)

FROM CourtCase CC
LEFT JOIN calendar.CaseAssociateEvent CCAE ON CCAE.CourtCaseID = CC.CourtCaseID
LEFT JOIN calendar.CaseEventHeader CEH ON CEH.CaseEventHeaderID = CCAE.CaseEventHeaderID
LEFT JOIN calendar.ScheduledDay SD ON SD.CaseEventHeaderID = CEH.CaseEventHeaderID
LEFT JOIN calendar.ScheduledEvent SE ON SE.CaseEventHeaderID = CEH.CaseEventHeaderID
LEFT JOIN calendar.ScheduledResult SR ON SR.ScheduledEventID = SE.ScheduledEventID
LEFT JOIN calendar.EventResultCodes ERC ON ERC.EventResultID = SR.EventResultID
LEFT JOIN calendar.MatterTypeCodes MTC ON MTC.MatterTypeID = CEH.MatterTypeID
LEFT JOIN calendar.EventTypeCodes ETC ON ETC.EventTypeID = SE.EventTypeID

ORDER BY CC.CaseDisplayNumber
OPTION (MAXDOP 2)

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ChargeDispo') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #ChargeDispo
CREATE TABLE #ChargeDispo(

  CaseDisplayNumber VARCHAR(20)
, Charge VARCHAR(20)
, ChargeClass VARCHAR(5)
, DispositionCD VARCHAR(2)
)
INSERT INTO #ChargeDispo
 SELECT DISTINCT CC.CaseDisplayNumber
            ,CCD.ARSCode Charge
            ,CCC.ChargeClass ChargeClass
            ,DC.DispositionCD Disposition


FROM CourtCase CC
JOIN CaseAction CA ON CA.CourtCaseID = CC.CourtCaseID
JOIN PartyCaseActionRole PCAR ON PCAR.CaseActionID = CA.CaseActionID
JOIN Charge C ON C.PartyCaseActionRoleID = PCAR.PartyCaseActionRoleID
JOIN ChargeActivity CAY ON CAY.ChargeID = C.ChargeID AND CAY.ChargeStatusID = 1
JOIN ChargeCodes CCD ON CCD.ChargeCodeID = CAY.ChargeCodeID 
JOIN ChargeClassCodes CCC ON CCC.ChargeClassID = CCD.ChargeClassID 
LEFT JOIN ChargeDisposition CD ON CD.ChargeActivityID = CAY.ChargeActivityID
LEFT JOIN DispositionStatusCodes DSC ON DSC.DispositionStatusID = CD.DispositionStatusID 
LEFT JOIN DispositionCodes DC ON DC.DispositionID = CD.DispositionID

WHERE DSC.DispositionStatusID = 1

ORDER BY CCC.ChargeClass
OPTION (MAXDOP 2)

SELECT DISTINCT CC.CaseDisplayNumber CaseNumber
               ,CC.FileDate FileDate
               ,EN.FullName Defendant
               ,CD.ChargeClass Class
               ,CD.DispositionCD DispositionID
               ,NE.EventType EventType
               ,NE.ScheduledDay ScheduledDay
               ,NE.EventResult EventResult
               ,PD.PayDate DueDate
               ,fnGetFinancialBalance(FP.financialpartyid) Balance

FROM CourtCase CC
JOIN CaseAction CA ON CA.CourtCaseID = CC.CourtCaseID AND CC.CaseStatusID = 1
JOIN PayDate PD ON PD.CaseActionID = CA.CaseActionID AND PD.EndDate IS NULL
JOIN PartyCaseActionRole PCAR ON PCAR.CaseActionID = CA.CaseActionID AND PCAR.PartyRoleID = 4
JOIN financial.FinancialParty FP ON FP.PartyID = PCAR.PartyID
JOIN Party P ON P.PartyID = PCAR.PartyID
JOIN PartyRoleCodes PRC ON PRC.PartyRoleID = PCAR.PartyRoleID AND PRC.PartyRoleID = 4
JOIN Entity E ON E.EntityID = P.EntityID
JOIN EntityName EN ON EN.EntityID = E.EntityID
JOIN #ChargeDispo CD ON CD.CaseDisplayNumber = CC.CaseDisplayNumber 
JOIN #NextEvent NE ON NE.CaseDisplayNumber = CC.CaseDisplayNumber AND NE.RowNum = 1

WHERE 
NE.ScheduledDay <= PD.PayDate
AND (CD.ChargeClass = 'CV' OR CD.ChargeClass = 'PK')
AND (CD.DispositionCD = '11' OR CD.DispositionCD = '12' OR CD.DispositionCD = '21' OR     CD.DispositionCD = '22')
AND fnGetFinancialBalance(FP.financialpartyid) > 0

ORDER BY PD.PayDate 
OPTION (MAXDOP 2)
```

My trouble is in the last WHERE statement.  I'm not sure if it even needs to be there either.  My results are almost perfect, I just need to get rid of rows IF the NE.MatterTypeID = 3, AND the NE.ScheduledDay is GREATER than PD.PayDate (basically get rid of all future court dates that are after the pay date).  Other than that, I want to show everything else.  This could really help me out on future queries as well.  I have been looking for similar problems, but can't find an answer that can really help me out.  Unless I'm not searching right, which could very possibly be the case.  I've tried IF, I've tried OR's, I've tried CASE (which confuses me a little).  The line:

```
NE.ScheduledDay <= PD.PayDate
```

works, I just need it to be a little more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you need to do is convert your logic to match the way you refer to it.  For example, if you say "x needs to be greater than y", your code should reflect that, not the opposite ("y needs to be <= x").  That just helps with clarity.

Your condition would then be

`Where NOT(NE.MatterTypeID = 3 and NE.ScheduledDay > PD.PayDate) AND --...`

Second, your issue is likely a `date` vs `datetime` problem.  If your dates are `datetime` values, you'll need to lop off the time data by casting to a date.  It may be possible for the scheduled day to be `11/5/2014 8:00 PM`, while the pay date is `11/5/2014 8:00 am`.  On the surface, you'd expect them to be the same, but the time value could be throwing you off.

I recommend changing the column type to `date` if you'll never use the time value.  That removes the need to lop off the time in future queries. If you can't do that, you can cast as a date to make the dates time-agnostic:

`Where NOT(NE.MatterTypeID = 3 and CAST( NE.ScheduledDay as date) > CAST(PD.PayDate as date) ) AND --...`

Comment: This was perfect! Thank you so much.  My data is pretty perfect now.  All I have to do now is speed it up! Thank you again!